# How to sum up previous rows value with current row in ms access query?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The input is as follows:

```
name  |  qty  
-------------
 A    |   10   
 B    |   20  
 C    |   20
```

The output should be:

```
Name    |  qty
---------------
 A      |   10
 B      |   30
 C      |   50
```

=>for first row the score should come as it is..

=>for second row it should be the sum of previous row and the current row..

=>for third row it should be the sum of the previous 2 rows and the current row..

How to write a ms access query for this one..
Help me out..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try the below link it might answer your question

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290136

Comment: Thank You So Much for your Valuable Response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got Answer....

(SELECT (IIF(ISNULL(((SELECT Sum(PROCESS.QTY) AS STOCK FROM PROCESS WHERE PROCESS.id <= BAL.id ))),0,((SELECT Sum(PROCESS.QTY) AS STOCK FROM PROCESS WHERE PROCESS.id <= BAL.id ) ))) FROM PROCESS AS BAL )